# What does eval(dir()[0]) do in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary, eval

I came across a solution for a program in python but I couldn't understand what it does even after searching. Could someone please explain me what this statement will do.

```
a, b, c = map(numpy.array,eval(dir()[0]))
```

Comment: Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: As a general rule, whenever you see a call to `eval` or `exec`, spit over your left shoulder three times and run away, because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: `eval(dir()[0])` is horrific and fragile. Do not take this as an example of what you should do in your own code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `eval(dir()[0])` part

Comment: [`dir()[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is the first name in the current local namespace, sorted alphabetically.  `eval` evaluates that name to get the object it represents.  `map` then iterates though it and does `numpy.array(x) for x in eval(dir()[0])`.  We then assume that there were three items in the `eval`ed object and assign the three arrays from `map` to those variables.

Comment: [Apparently this is supposed to be an exploit vector against auto-grading of online code challenges](https://hans.codes/exploiting-side-information-codefights-challenges/), which is why they're doing things that make no sense in a normal program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir), when called without arguments returns the names of all local variables, similar to `locals().keys()`.

```
def f(y):
     print(dir())  # prints ['y']
```

Then, obviously, `dir()[0]` is the name of the first of the local variables and `eval(dir()[0])` evaluates the variable name, i.e. returns the first local variable's value.

```
def f(y):
     print(dir())  # prints ['y']
     print(dir()[0])  # prints 'y'
     print(eval(dir()[0]))  # prints the value of y
```

For example:

```
>>> f(77)
['y']
y
77
>>> f([1,2,3])
['y']
y
[1, 2, 3]
```

Function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) calls the first argument (which has to be callable) with each of the values in the second argument (which has to be iterable), and generates the results e.g.

```
>>> for result in map(str.upper, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
...     print(result)
...
FOO
BAR
BAZ
```

Combining those together, and assuming that the first local variable is a list named `first_variable`, then this code:

```
a, b, c = map(numpy.array,eval(dir()[0]))
```

would be the same as this code:

```
a, b, c = first_variable
a = numpy.array(a)
b = numpy.array(b)
c = numpy.array(c)
```